# Vuejs -- Browserify -- How to use LESS variables "@"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browserify

I am also new to vue.

I am having trouble with Variables in my less files.

I include them like so:

```
require("./colors.less");
```

..and it works! But I get:

> ParseError: Unexpected character '@'

This is how I setup variables and the source of the error:

```
//colors.less
@aqua: #5CBFBF;
@aquadark: #1C939B;
@mediumgray :#d1d2ce;
@blue       :#376784;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need node-lessify

cd into your project and do:

```
npm install node-lessify
```

then find your package.json at the root of your project.

make the following additions:

```
"scripts": {
    "node-lessify" :"node-lessify src/path-to-your-less-file.less > bundle.js",
    //....leave what is here already alone, don't forget the trailing comma
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "node-lessify",
    //....leave what is here already alone, don't forget the trailing comma
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-lessify":"0.1.4",
    //....leave what is here already alone, don't forget the trailing comma
```